Question about integration of a meromorphic function
Let $f,g$ be two entire functions that are not polynomials, which satisfy the following:

$f(0)=g(0)=1$ and $f'(0),g'(0)\neq 0$;
On the real line, $\lim_{z\to+\infty} f(z)=\lim_{z\to-\infty}g(z)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{z\to-\infty}f(z)=\lim_{z\to+\infty}g(z)=0$;
$|g(z)|\leq1$ on $Re(z)\geq 0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on $Re(z)\leq0$, with equality attained if and only if $z=0$.

Now, define
$$
F(z) = \frac{f(z)g(z)}{1-g(z)}.
$$
Clearly $F$ is meromorphic and has no poles on $Re(z)>0$. My question is what can we say about the poles of $F$ on $Re(z)\leq 0$. In particular, I wish to evaluate, for some real $\gamma,t>0$, the integration
$$
\lim_{T\to+\infty}\int_{-T}^T F(\gamma+iu)e^{(\gamma+iu)t}du
$$
which I know exist and is actually bounded for all $\gamma,t>0$. Is there any hope of using something similar to the residue theorem to express this integration using the set of poles of $F(z)$ (i.e. set of zeros of $g(w)=1$)?
For an example, consider $g(w)=(1-e^{-w})/w$ with a removable singularity $g(w)=1$ at $w=0$, and $f(w)=g(-w)$.
Edit: Can assume that $|f(w)|,|g(w)|\leq e^{a|w|}$ for some finite $a<+\infty$.
